# Function that takes various arguments of various type and returns certain object in functional Java

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming

Let's say I've got some lambda expressions as below:

```
        Function<String, List<String>> flines = fileName -> {
    //Puts all lines from file into List and returns a list
        };

        Function<List<String>, String> join = listOfLines -> {
    //Concatenates all lines from list and returns them as String
        };

        Function<String, List<Integer>> collectInts = str -> {
    //Returns all Integer occurences from given String
        };
```

And I want to create a function, let's say `resultType convertBy(Function<T,S>...args)`
So I can combine arguments and return cerain result:

```
List<String> lines = fileConv.convertBy(flines) //returns list of lines
String text = fileConv.convertBy(flines, join); //returns s String from concatenated Strings
List<Integer> ints = fileConv.convertBy(flines, join, collectInts); //returns list of Integers from string
Integer sumints = fileConv.convertBy(flines, join, collectInts, sum); ////returns list of Integers from string and sums it
```

Is it somehow possible to do in Java?

**EDIT: I CAN'T use overloading**

Comment: Why not simply use `flines.andThen(join).andThen(collectInts).andThen(sum)`?

Comment: You are approaching the problem in the wrong way. You want to compose functions using an *imperative* approach, while you should do as @JBNizet suggests and make your method receive only one function, and use function composition to transform all your functions into one function that your method can handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using generics, **you need to declare the type variables involved**. Since defining a method which chains calls using a variable number of generic functions (with varargs) would require a variable number of type variables, that's not possible to do.

It would not be possible, at compile time, to guarantee that each of functions given with varargs would use types so that they are compatible when chaining the calls.
You can do it, **but not in a type-safe way**. Any mismatch on the input/output types of the functions will result in a `ClassCastException` at runtime.

```
private static <T, U> U convertBy(T arg, Function... functions) {
  Object result = arg;
  for (Function f : functions) {
    result = f.apply(result);
  }
  return (U) result;
}

@Test
public void test() {
  Function<String, Integer> f1 = s -> s.length();
  Function<Integer, Double> f2 = i -> i*2.0;
  Double d = convertBy("test", f1, f2);
  assertThat(d).isEqualTo(8.0);
}
```

You can, however, **manually define variants of that method** that does the chaining by overloading it:

```
private static <T, U> U convertBy(T arg, Function<T, U> func1) {
  return func1.apply(arg);
}

private static <T, U, V> V convertBy(T arg, Function<T, U> func1, Function<U, V> func2) {
  return func2.apply(func1.apply(arg));
}

private static <T, U, V, X> X convertBy(T arg, Function<T, U> func1, Function<U, V> func2, Function<V, X> func3) {
  return func3.apply(func2.apply(func1.apply(arg)));
}
```